# Rails edit form not working properly with angular

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, angularjs

I am using angular client side form validation in my rails form. But if I use angular `model` in any `input field` then the fields looks empty and not prefilling with the current database data as normal.

Here is an input element with angular error validation. This `field` is not getting pre-populated with the `listing_name` data which is already in the database

```
<div class="col-md-12">
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :listing_name %><br/>
    <%= f.text_field :listing_name, placeholder: "Make it short and catchy", "ng-model" => "editRoom.listing_name", "ng-required": true, "ng-minlength": 2, class: "form-control input-lg" %>
  </div>
  <p class="error validation-error" ng-show="editRoom['room[listing_name]'].$invalid && editRoom['room[listing_name]'].$touched">
    This field is required
  </p>
</div>
```

But if I remove the `ng-model` from the input field it works as expected.I dont have any `controller` or anything for angular. The form is just a normal rails form and am only using angular for form validation. How can I fix this in this scenario?

**Update**

I added `ng-app="editForm"` and it worked first without even declaring the module and it now fails after a server restart and asking for module. SO I created a module but now the console error is gone but the form is again not prefilling with form data.seems like a glitch.. any help

I am using `"angular": "~1.4.8"` via bower

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add an `ng-app` directive somewhere in the document.

```
<body ng-app='someApp'>
  <!-- Other elements -->
  <div class="col-md-12">
  <!-- Other elements -->
</body>
```

Comment: actually added ng-app but didnt gave a name. But If I gave a name it works. Thank you.